# set audio priorities

Tags: sound, blacklist

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 which seems to mix alsa and pulse-audio in strange and magical ways. I have potentially 4 output devices:

1. notebook speakers
2. audio in docking station
3. terminal with audio
4. headsets

It's pretty clear that if I switch on my headset I want them to be the audio sink. And when I switch them off it always reverts to the docking station which is the one device incapable of playing sound.

I have spent hours reading about this problem with threads going back to 2005. You can tell pulse audio one preferred device. You can maybe black list devices. But the examples use numbers 1,2,3 and I've got numbers that change and only 3 are visible in pactl

76. alsa_output.usb-DisplayLink_Plugable_UD-ULTCDL_60567033-02.analog-stereo
77. bluez_sink.00_16_94_36_F7_4D.a2dp_sink
78. alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo

But setting->sound panel shows me 5 devices:

1. Speaker- Built in audio
2. Digital Ouput (S/PDIF) - Plugable UD-ULTCDL
3. Analog Output - Plugable ED-ULTCDL
4. HDMI / Displayport - Biult-in Audio
5. Headset - PXC 550

I would simply like a priority arrangement: 5, 4, 1 with 2, 3 never used.

It's not that is complicated to do so. It is impossible to understand how to do so.

pactl list | grep profile | wc

gives me 24 hits. 24 defined profiles on my clean install. Useful tips that are 8 years old and no longer work.

Is there a reasonable method of setting audio device prioritie? My priorities are fairly obvious. If nothing is connected use notebook audio. If external display connected use its audio. If headsets on use them.